# How to check if some strings are "in" and some "not in" a list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, contains

How to make this code work?

I want to check if some substrings are in list and some are not.

```
if 'A_' and 'V' and '3' and not 'ES' and not 'SF' in my_list[0:3]:
    print("It's True")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
if all(x in L for x in wanted) and all(x not in L for x in not_wanted):
   # do stuff
```

Comment: Can you show me how to use this function with my example ?

Comment: @Luk: Just use `L = my_list[:3]; wanted = ["A_", "V", "3"]; not_wanted = ["ES", "SF"]`